# Vim prints options on quit

Tags: vimrc, options, macos

I've noticed that recently when I quit vim it prints the following text to the terminal:

```
--- Options ---
  background=dark  helplang=en  relativenumber
  cursorline  number  scroll=11
  runtimepath=~/.config/nvim,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-sensible/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-multiple-cursors/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/molokai/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-colors-solarized/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-commentary/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/lucario/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-auto-save/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/Improved-Syntax-Highlighting-Vim/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vimtex/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-sneak/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/pretty-vim-python/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/supertab/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/simpylfold/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-fish/,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-airline/,/etc/xdg/nvim,~/.local/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.0_1/share/nvim/runtime,/usr/share/nvim/site/after,/usr/local/share/nvim/site/after,~/.local/share/nvim/site/after,/etc/xdg/nvim/after,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight/after,~/.config/nvim/plugged/vimtex/after,~/.config/nvim/after
```

I'm on a mac and I use neovim but the same behavior happens in regular vim. I don't think I changed anything recently but here is my vimrc file:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'tpope/vim-sensible'
" Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'terryma/vim-multiple-cursors'
Plug 'tomasr/molokai'
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'

"Plug 'severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap'
Plug 'raphamorim/lucario'
Plug '907th/vim-auto-save'
"
Plug 'octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight'
Plug 'dragfire/Improved-Syntax-Highlighting-Vim'
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
"Plug 'klen/python-mode'
"Plug 'hdima/python-syntax'
"Plug 'dragfire/improved-syntax-highlighting-vim'
"Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
" Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion'
" Plug 'goldfeld/vim-seek'
Plug 'justinmk/vim-sneak'
"Plug 'vim-scripts/TagHighlight'
"Plug 'xolox/vim-easytags'
"Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'
Plug 'sentientmachine/pretty-vim-python'
Plug 'ervandew/supertab'
Plug 'tmhedberg/simpylfold'

Plug 'dag/vim-fish'
Plug 'bling/vim-airline'
" Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
call plug#end()


colo molokai

"let python_highlight_builtins = 1
"let g:pymode_python = 'python3'
if has("gui_vimr")
 let g:molokai_original = 1
endif

inoremap jk <Esc>

set number
set relativenumber
set cursorline
set 
syntax on

let g:multi_cursor_exit_from_insert_mode = 0
let g:multi_cursor_insert_maps = {'j':1}


"set nofoldenable
set foldlevel=99
set clipboard=unnamed
nnoremap <esc> :noh<return><esc>

set spell
set mouse=a

let g:vimtex_view_method = 'skim'
let g:vimtex_view_general_viewer
      \ = '/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline'
let g:vimtex_view_general_options = '-r @line @pdf @tex'
```

I don't see any option that could be causing it but I've tried disabling plugins randomly but couldn't come up with a thing which removes the printing

Comment: Instead of disabling the plugins randomly try to follow the guidelines in [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) (especially confirming that the problem comes from your vimrc with `vim -U NONE` and edit your question with what you found while debugging your `.vimrc` it will make it easier for the others to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your `.vimrc`:

```
...
set cursorline
set                " <- HERE
syntax on
...
```

This `set` command must be causing it.

Looks like during initialization Vim
dumps output to terminal, but you don't see it until
Vim is closed.  I get similar behaviour if I put stray `set` to my `.vimrc`
file (although I do need to press enter to skip the output, but this must be due to much bigger number of changed options).